# Linq Group by and sum problems

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following entities:

An account class with a list of subscriptions:

```
public class Account
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Account ID
    /// </summary>
    public string ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A List with all subscriptions
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

the subscription class with a list of variations and add ons:

```
public class Subscription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Subscription ID
    /// </summary>
    public string ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quantity of the subscription.
    /// </summary>
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A list with all subscription add ons
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<AddOn> AddOns { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A List with all subscription variations
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Variation> Variations { get; set; }
}
```

the add on class with a list of variations:

```
public class AddOn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets add on id
    /// </summary>
    public string ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quantity of the add on.
    /// </summary>
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A List with all add on variations
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Variation> Variations { get; set; }

}
```

And the variation class:

```
public class Variation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Variation ID
    /// </summary>
    public string ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// offerUri
    /// </summary>
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Variation Value
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Variation Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to group all add ons with specific Code and sum the quantity. For example I tried:

```
var groupAddOnsByCode = acc.Subscriptions.Select(s => s.AddOns.GroupBy(a => a.Variations.Select(v => v.Code).FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
```

This one correct groups add ons but I want a list with with add ons per subscription group by code and total quantity per code.

For example if a Subscription has X number of add ons and the Code of each add on is 1, 2, ..., X, I want to group by the add ons by Code and total Quantity with this Code. I expect the result will be something like if I have the following structure:

A pseudo-code with current structure(**Code** refers to **Variation** Class that each add on has):

```
Subscription {
 //a list with X number of add ons
 AddOn1 = { Variation = { Code = 1 }, Quantity = 2 },
 AddOn2 = { Variation = { Code = 2 }, Quantity = 3 },
 ...
 AddOnX = { Variation = { Code = X }, Quantity = 4 }
}
```

What I expect:

```
Subscription {
    AddOn1 { Variation = { Code = 1 }, Quantity = totalAmountOfQuantityForAddOnsWithCode = 1 },
    ...
    AddOnX { Variation = { Code = X }, Quantity = totalAmountOfQuantityForAddOnsWithCode = X },
}
```

You can use this [**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBAipd) to test dummy data.

Sorry for the long post and I will appreciate any help. Also keep in mind my c# and Linq knowledge is limited.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to collect the AddOns from every Subscription into a single set and then group that master set by Variation.Code?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, and to be more specific. Let's say I have a subscription with 20 add ons with codes 1, 2, 3. I want a Subscription with 3 Add ons and the total quantity of each with the same code.

Comment: Ok just to make sure, you don't want to combine stuff across different subscriptions right?  So if you have 2 subscriptions each with 10 add ons, you want two completely separate groups of add-ons and not one group from the 20?

Comment: Subscriptions should stay the same. Only the add ons of each subscription should change.

Comment: Could you provide a full blown example (`Quantity = totalAmountOfQuantityForAddOnsWithCode = X` doesn't help me at least, sorry)?

Comment: @Caramiriel For example a subscription has 6 add ons. Two of add ons has Code 1, other two has Code 2 and last two has Code 3. Each of them has Quantity 1. What I want as result is a subscription with 3 add Ons(Code refers to Variation), Code 1: Qty = 2, Code 2: Qty =2 and Code 3: Qty = 3

Comment: *" I want as result is a subscription with 3 add Ons, Code 1: Qty = 2, Code 2: Qty =2 and Code 3: Qty = 3"* but `AddOn` doesn't have `Code`?

Comment: @ArghyaC Sorry my bad. Add on with the specific Variation Code :) Also edit my OP to be more clear.

Comment: Can you please update the last section of your question show this? What happens to the other fields of AddOn ?

Comment: try this  ````acc.Subscriptions.SelectMany(x=>x.AddOns)
   .GroupBy(a=> a.Variations.FirstOrDefault().Code)
   .GroupBy(g=> new {code=g.Key , count= g.Count()},g=> g.ToList())````; in your fiddle.

Comment: @ArghyaC Updated my OP. Can you please confirm is more clear?(I provide some pseudo-code to be more easy to understand sorry if I misdirect you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following might produce the desired result

```
var result = acc.Subscriptions.Select(s => new
{
    Subscription = s,
    AddOns = s.AddOns.SelectMany(a => a.Variations, (a, v) => new { a, v })
        .GroupBy(e => e.v.Code, (key, elements) => new 
        { 
            Code = key,
            Quantity = elements.Sum(e => e.a.Quantity)
        }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will run my tests and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not completely sure this is what you want, try this

```
var codes = addOns.SelectMany(a => a.Variations).Select(v => v.Code).Distinct();

var addOnsByCode = new List<AddOn>(); //your desired result
foreach (var code in codes)
{
    var addOnsWithThisCode = addOns.Where(a => a.Variations.Any(v => v.Code == code));
    addOnsByCode.Add(new AddOn{
        Variations = new List<Variation> { new Variation { Code = code } },
        Quantity = addOnsWithThisCode.Sum(a => a.Quantity),
        ID = string.Join("_", addOnsWithThisCode.Select(a => a.ID)) //not required>
    });
}
```

Where `addOns` is a `List<AddOn>`, for example

```
var addOns = new List<AddOn> {
    new AddOn { 
        ID = "1", 
        Quantity = 5, 
        Variations = new List<Variation> 
        {
            new Variation { Code = "A" },
            new Variation { Code = "B" }
        } 
    },
    new AddOn { 
        ID = "2", 
        Quantity = 7, 
        Variations = new List<Variation> 
        {
            new Variation { Code = "B" },
            new Variation { Code = "C" }
        } 
    },
    new AddOn { 
        ID = "3", 
        Quantity = 9, 
        Variations = new List<Variation> 
        {
            new Variation { Code = "D" },
            new Variation { Code = "A" }
        } 
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your effort but I will go with @IvanStoev.

Comment: Sure, whichever approach solves your problem the best.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly I think that the following method will help.  I added a method within your `Subscription` class to group its add-ons by its Variation Codes and then sum the quantities of various codes.  The key to my code is using `SelectMany` to break a single Add-On with multiple variants into separate elements that pair Code and Quantity.  Then you can group the broken-up elements.

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetAddonGroups()
{
    //spreading out each Add-on into multiple elements, each with a Code and quantity
    var addOnVariationsWithQuantity = this.AddOns
        .SelectMany(ad =>  ad.Variations
                    .Select(v => new {Code = v.Code, Quantity = ad.Quantity}));

    //group by Code and Sum the quantity
    var addOnGroups = addOnVariationsWithQuantity
                        .GroupBy(v => v.Code)
                        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, 
                                      grp => grp.Sum( el => el.Quantity));
    return addOnGroups;
}
```

[Forked Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GnlgU)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your effort but I will go with @IvanStoev.

Comment: @AlexChar no problem.  We ended up having similar-ish approaches, with the SelectMany.  I'm just glad this helped a bit.